# insert 0 into value in a specific pattern in R

Tags: r, string, leading-zero

I feel like this should be fairly simple, but I'm stuck. I have a list of isolates that start with the letter P + varying numbers. I would like to have each to have 4 numbers with leading 0s to fill in. For example, "P10" -> "P0010" and "P104" -> "P0104".
I extracted the number and was trying to glue it together by adding 0's, but I'm getting an error I don't understand. I think it might be due to the `rep` function, but not super certain. Any help would be appreciated!

```
dat <- data.frame(isolate = c("P10", "P104", "P2"))

dat %>% 
    mutate(num = str_extract(isolate, "[:digit:]+")) %>% 
    mutate(final = str_glue("P", rep(0,4-length(num)), num))
```

The error message is as follows:

```
Error in `mutate()`:
ℹ In argument: `final = str_glue("P", rep(0, 4 - length(num)), num)`.
Caused by error:
! All unnamed arguments must be length 1
```

Comment: Use `str_pad` to pad the number with 0s. `final = str_glue("P", str_pad(num, width = 4, side = "left", pad = "0"))`.

Comment: Your `rep` would work for a single line, but `rep` isn't vectorized in the way you need to work on all the rows at once.